# Cannot call the same method on all base classes

Tags: python

I would like to call the same methods on all mixins of my class. Here are two variants:

```
class MixinA(object):
    def get_id(self):
        return "A"


class MixinB(object):
    def get_id(self):
        return "B"


class Base(object):
    def get_id(self):
        for base_class in inspect.getmro(self.__class__):
            return ",".join(base_class.get_id())


class Instance(MixinA, MixinB, Base):
    pass


class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_multiple_mixin_methods(self):
        """
        Sadly, we cannot call all mixin methods.
        :return:
        """

        ids = set(Instance().get_id())
        print(ids)
        assert ids == {"A", "B"}
```

Sadly, this fails. I only get 'A' back. I would like a list containing 'A' and 'B', order does not matter.

Anything I am doing wrong here?

Many thanks

Comment: Shouldn't Base be the first in inheritance for this to work ? Instance.get_id() just resolves to MixinA.get_id() right now.

Comment: I believe you would need to do something like this to get the behavior you're after: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20450911/python-call-parent-method-multiple-inheritance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to call to super.
super calls the next method in the MRO so you will call A => B.
you don't need the Base class.

```
class MixinA(object):
    def get_id(self):
        return "A", super(MixinA, self).get_id()


class MixinB(object):
    def get_id(self):
        return "B"


class Instance(MixinA, MixinB):
    pass
```

First the `Instance().get_id()` will call to `A.get_id()` then
the call to super will call the next method in the MRO that is B

**Update**

```
class MixinA(object):
    def get_id(self):
        return "A"


class MixinB(object):
    def get_id(self):
        return "B"


class Base(object):
    def get_id(self):
       return set([base_class.get_id(self) for base_class in inspect.getmro(self.__class__)[2:-1]])


class Instance(Base, MixinA, MixinB):
    pass
```

Not like before the mixins are independent. in this example you need the Base class to be first in The MRO

Comment: But then I need to think about the relationship between mixins. I would them to be able work independently and without knowledge of each other.

Comment: Thank you for the update. The solution to place the Base class first seems to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet passes your tests, but it's brittle and IMHO a sure design smell. Also it requires that `Base` comes first in the mro (but that's usually what you want when using a base class and mixins):

```
class MixinA(object):
    def get_id(self):
        return "A"


class MixinB(object):
    def get_id(self):
        return "B"


class Base(object):
    def get_id(self):
        ids = set()
        mro = self.__class__.__mro__
        start = mro.index(Base) + 1
        for cls in mro__[start:-1]:
            get_id = getattr(cls, "get_id", None)
            if get_id:
                id = cls.get_id(self)
                ids.add(id)
        return ids

class Instance(Base, MixinA, MixinB):
    pass
```

You can get it to work (well, kind of...) with `super` calls too but it's not that pretty either and things start getting ugly when you add a third mixin (test the snippet with and without `MixinC` in `Instance` bases to see what I mean):

```
def get_super_id(id, cls, obj):
    try:
        supid = super(cls, obj).get_id()
        return id, supid 
    except AttributeError:
        return id

class MixinA(object):
    def get_id(self):
        return get_super_id("A", MixinA, self)


class MixinB(object):
    def get_id(self):
        return get_super_id("B", MixinB, self)

class MixinC(object):
    def get_id(self):
        return get_super_id("C", MixinC, self)


class Base(object):
    pass

class Instance(Base, MixinA, MixinB, MixinC):
    pass
```

Actually the thing I dislike most with the whole idea is that `get_id` returns either a single value or a collection. This breaks expectations in unpredictable ways.